# Using ! with object name in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a column "SchoolName" in my educations table and I want to check the following code:

```
<% @user_education.each do |e| %>
<% if !e.SchoolName.nil? and e.Private? == "1" %>
<%= check_box(:ChkBx_Education, "", true) %>
<%= label(:lb_Profession, "Education") %>
<% else %>
<%= check_box(:ChkBx_Education,"" ) %>
<%= label(:lb_Profession, "Education") %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

The @user_education variable comes from the controller page i.e `@user_education=Education.where(:UserID => current_user.id)`  My question is whether this statement `!e.SchoolName.nil?` is right or wrong?  I want to ensure that if `SchoolName` is not `nil` and `Private? is equal to "1"` then it checks the checkbox.

Comment: you're coding against all conventions. Good luck to those maintaining your project: camelcase + methods finishing by `?` should return booleans

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct convention of the following line would be something like this, taking `Private?` as a boolean columns. The correct code following rails convention would have been something like this

```
<% if e.school_name.present? and e.is_private? %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, you have broken the rules of developing an application with Ruby.

Active Record uses naming conventions for the columns in database tables, depending on the purpose of these columns.

The names of attributes in Ruby should always be uncapitalised, just like local variables.

Foreign keys - These should be named following this pattern:  singularized_table_name_id (ex: item_id, order_id). These are the fields that Active Record will look for when you create associations between your models.

Primary keys - By default, Active Record will use an integer column named id as the table's primary key. When using Rails Migrations to create your tables, this column will be automatically created.

I think you should refer to [Ruby Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) and read it carefully before working with any application.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, you need to rename your database columns to be lower case in order to make initial syntax improvements:

```
<% @user_education.each do |e| %>
    <% if e.school_name && e.private? %> =-> .private? should return true / false if column is boolean
       <%= check_box(:checkbox_education, "", true) %>
       <%= label(:checkbox_education, "Education") %>
    <% else %>
       <%= check_box(:checkbox_education,"") %>
       <%= label(:checkbox_education, "Education") %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```